# how add server side Anchor to a div form code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor, server-side, code-behind

plz see the aspx below first :

```
<div id="divFilesBody">
              <div class="divFilesBody_Row">
                <%= Files %>
                <a id="MyAnchor1" runat="server" OnServerClick="AnchorForDwonload_Click">Server Side Anchor 1</a>
            </div>
```

MyAnchor1 Serverside click event works perfect!
i want to make something like that from code behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using FileExplorer.Classes;

namespace FileExplorer.en
{
    public partial class Download : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Files = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
...
            foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
            {
                Files += "<a class='MyAnchor2' runat='server' OnServerClick='AnchorForDwonload_Click'>";
                Files += "Server Side Anchor 2";
                Files += "</a>";
            }
        Files += "<a id='MyAnchor3' runat='server' OnServerClick='AnchorForDwonload_Click'>";
        Files += "Server Side Anchor 3";
        Files += "</a>";
        }

        protected void AnchorForDwonload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Server Side Anchor Works");
        }

    }
}
```

but MyAnchor2 does not work after firing page load...
how can i solve this issue?

**EDIT**
i added MyAnchor3 After comment (An Anchor With ID) -> still does not work

the output html is like this :

> ```
>         <a id='MyAnchor3' runat='server' OnServerClick='AnchorForDwonload_Click'>
>         Server Side Anchor 3
>        </a>
> ```

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the `ID` for myanchor2 ?

Comment: @JonH thanks for commnet / you are right / i should add many of them / so i removed id!

Comment: Try this should help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351225/how-to-dynamically-render-asp-net-controls-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the right way to create dynamic controls in ASP.NET. You can use LinkButton controls to achieve this:

You should be doing something like this instead:

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFilesBody" runat="server">
    <!-- resolves to a DIV -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)  
{   
    //create controls at every page load and assign the same ids to the controls
    //to preserve click events

    foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))  
    { 
        //create a new linkbutton
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn .ID = String.Format("lnk_{0}", pnlFilesBody.Controls.Count);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btn.Text = String.Format("Server Side Anchor {0}", pnlFilesBody.Controls.Count);

        //add the linkbutton to the files body panel
        pnlFilesBody.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //put your click event logic here
}
```